# Permission inherit strange in centos linux

Tags: linux, centos, permissions

**System**: CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

**Problem**: in same system have same umask: 022 but in `/B/test/2018` folder have strange issue of inheritation when create folder and move file

```
test@CMS-OPER-01 ~]$ umask 
0022
```

**Flow working**:

- Tomcat run as root:

  ```
  [test@CMS-OPER-01 ~]$ ps aux | grep tomcat
  root 15633 2.1 3.4 14387604 1118180 ? Sl 2017 2848:00 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  ```
- Webapps do move file from folder `/A/test/2018` to `/B/test/2018`

**Storage mount in the system**:

```
[test@OPER-01 201801]$
1.1.1.10:/hnas1-data01
                      200T  176T   25T  88% /A
1.1.1.11:/hnas1-data02
                      200T   72T  129T  36% /B
```

**Parent folder same permission**:

```
[test@OPER-01 -]$ getfacl /A/test/201801
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: A/test/201801
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

[test@OPER-01 -]$ getfacl /B/test/201801
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: B/test/201801
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

**Folder create in parent folder, and file moved have different permission although have same umask 022**:

```
[test@OPER-01 -]$ getfacl /A/test/201801/*
# file: A/test/201801/197275
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

[test@OPER-01 -]$ getfacl /B/test/201801/*
# file: B/test/201801/197258
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::--x
```

Answer (score 0):

umask and default ACL (not present in your case) affect newly created objects only. I.e. for regular files some process has to execute `open()` (or `mkdir()` for directories.

The permissions are determined at creation time (from the `open()` parameters, umask and maybe default ACLs) and stored in the inode.

If a file is just moved (within a file system) then `rename()` is called instead and this syscall does not affect the inode at all, just where in the file system hierarchy it is shown.